# extjs find child span id from parent

Tags: extjs

I have a HTML as follows, I want to get id of the div whose span value is "Seat History" and parent id of the div is 'tabs2'.

I actually want to hide the div if it has span in the child of value "Seat History"

ID History                                                   

      
     
     Seat History

Comment: are you trying to hide a tab or panel?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Ext.query("*[class=Seat History]");
```

Check this [DomQuery](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aDomQuery_v1.1_Basics)